# How to create a program on top of Visio?

Tags: automation, visio

Is it possible to make a standalone/independent (from visio) program that is built on visio. Say, can i attach *some of the design templates* and visio drawing page on to my form??
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Visio supports VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa201749(office.10).aspx). With that, you can add all kinds of interactivity to your document.

And, you can embed visio in another program with [the activex control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168480(office.11).aspx).

Both of these methods require visio to be installed on the machine (if that's what you were getting at by the "independent" comment).

The [Visio Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=F9ED50B0-C7DF-4FB8-89F8-DB2932E624F7&displaylang=en) may or may not install the activex control or support VBA, I don't know.

Comment: Wouldn't that be considered 'dependent'? Since the VBA scripts depend on visio running (i.e. they don't run separately)

Comment: i see. so it's not possible what i wanted to do. that is to create a flowcharting and analyzing program out of visio. :'(

Comment: @webdestroya - yes it wouldn't. so there is no way you can create a program with some of the functionality of visio/any other ms office product.

Comment: "independent from visio" and "built on visio" are mutually exclusive. You can either write your own visio-like program, or you can use visio (or you could use an open source "visio" program like [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia)). Not sure what you're looking to accomplish, just giving a few ideas.

Comment: The Visio Viewer has a COM API, but it's just for controlling what to load and view - no modifying diagrams

Answer (score 0):

There's a value stream mapping tool called SigmaFlow VSM that is an application built on Visio like you want to make.  Basically the tool loads up Visio and strips out a lot of the Visio toolbars and puts their own UI in.  Obviously it requires you have Visio installed.

There's a similar tool called eVSM that leaves the Visio UI in place, but provides a toolbar and templates and stencils for the purpose of building value stream maps.

I prefer the eSVM approach, where you end up giving the user the full ability to do whatever they want within Visio, while making the very specific task of Value Stream Map diagram creation easy.